# Generate XML and JSON file using single XSLT

Tags: xslt

I already have an XSLT which takes XML input, transforms it and gives me XML output.
But is there a way where I can use same XSLT, and fetch the transformed XML output and convert it into JSON.

Comment: You can transform the original XML directly to JSON, without going through an intermediate XML file.-- P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I want to convert the transformed XML to JSON and not the original XML. The version is 2.0

Comment: That would be a separate transformation, using a separate set of instructions. You *could* use the same stylesheet, with two separate sets of instructions - but there would be no advantage whatsoever to this compared to having two stylesheets. On the contrary, two separate stylesheets would be easier to maintain. It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish here. Do you need both XML and JSON as the result? If so, you can use two `xsl:result-document` instructions in the same stylesheet.

Comment: Yes I need both XML and JSON as the result

Comment: Well, if you think it's easier to produce the JSON from the output XML, then write the result tree to a variable first. Then use one `xsl:result-document` instruction to output the XML, and another to convert the tree in a variable to JSON and output it.

Comment: Do you have any sample xslt for this please. It would help me to build the required output.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small and artificial example that you could use as your starting point:

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <name>Bravo</name>
        <value>2.25</value>
    </item>
    <item id="3">
        <name>Charlie</name>
        <value>33</value>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="output-xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- write XML to output file -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$output-xml"/>
    <!-- produce a JSON file as additional output -->
    <xsl:result-document href="json.txt" method="text">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$output-xml" mode="json"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <array>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </array>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <object name="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </object>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="array" mode="json">
    <!-- array -->
    <xsl:text>[&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object" mode="json">
    <!-- object -->
    <xsl:text>&#9;{"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>" : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array>
   <object name="Alpha">101</object>
   <object name="Bravo">2.25</object>
   <object name="Charlie">33</object>
</array>
```

**Output file "json.txt"**

```
[
    {"Alpha" : 101},
    {"Bravo" : 2.25},
    {"Charlie" : 33}
]
```